# boot error - can't find i386-pcnormal.mod

Tags: grubrescue

I have very little knowledge, please be patient, I'm trying.

After trying to increase a partition to update Ubuntu, my PC restarted into grub rescue.

I tried the "set boot" situation, but it can't find the  **i386-pcnormal.mod**.
I have shot a  [photo with my error message and what I've tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSn9h.jpg)

I am downloading Kubuntu as I'm typing and my next step will be to try to install it all over again.
I'm not worried about losing data - it's a "toy" computer for the purpose of learning.

Please help me learn.

Comment: *"After trying to increase a partition to update Ubuntu"* can mean many things. I'd recommend booting with a Live USB and installing `boot-repair` to it. Then run `boot-repair` and link the results to your question. The `boot-repair` instructions can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair